# JQuery .append() close div automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, joomla, append

I want to integrate [this sidebar](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/08/28/transitions-for-off-canvas-navigations/) menu into my Joomla website in a form of module.

The problem is that I need to place some code just after  tag and the closing tags before the  here is the structure:

```
<body>

  <!-- Start of the code that should be after body-->

    <div id="st-container" class="st-container">        
        <nav class="st-menu st-effect-1" id="menu-1">
            <!-- Side bar content goes here-->
        </nav>  

        <div class="st-pusher">
            <div class="st-content">
                <div class="st-content-inner">
                    <div class="main clearfix">';

                        <!-- Website content goes here -->
```

```
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
```

So I need to append some code just after the body and other code before the closing of body.

What did I try ?

1/ I tried to use JQuery function .append() and prependTo()

```
            $script  = "(function($){\n";
            $script  .= "$(document).ready(function(){\n";

            $script  .= "$('body').append(\"$c2\");\n";
            $script  .= "$( \"$c\" ).prependTo( \"body\" );\n";
            $script .=      "});    \n";
            $script .=      "})(jQuery);" ;


$code2 = '</div></div></div></div></div>' ;
```

=> the divs are closed automatically and the $code2 wasn't added to code ..

2/ I tried wrap function

```
$script  = "(function($){\n";
$script  .= "$(document).ready(function(){\n";

$script  .= "$('#all').wrap(\"$cf\");\n";
$script .=      "});    \n";
$script .=      "})(jQuery);" ;
```

Comment: Dont use JavaScript to build up your view! If you guy are using joomla try to use its template engine. Make your self understand how "views" and also the MVC pattern in joomla works. Check this article: How to add a span element to menu entries in Joomla - http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:How_to_add_a_span_element_to_menu_entries

Comment: is there any chance to use this http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/08/28/transitions-for-off-canvas-navigations/ without the obligation to have the code splitted ... it means I can but the code anywhere I want ... not some code after body and other code before body ... then I can use the Joomla standard module...

Comment: @lin I have already done this using a Joomla plugin, but now I want it to be an instalable module, so the only solution I thisnk that I have is Javascript ... correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @Dev4life "be an instalable module", what do you mean with it? Also joomla modules are able to use the MVC Pattern. Iam sure u dont need to use JavaScript. If your modules view is dynamic use AJAX. ;)

Comment: So you are telling that you are doing something like: `$('body').append('</div></div></div></div></div>');` ??? If ya, its wrong, append() parse string to DOM node object, check DOC on how to use append(). Anyway, i don't know joomla but i'm pretty sure @lin is correct

Comment: @A.Wolff I think it's true, I should not relay on JS to structure the document, but is there a way to use the SideBarTransition script without the constrain of wrapping all the content of body

Comment: @Dev4life I'm afraid, i cannot answer to this question because i don't know this plugin at all

Comment: @lin yeah I know I can use mvc inside a module but the script SideBarTransition works only if I wrap the code of the body... how to implement that behavior with a module wihtout using JS

Comment: @Dev4life try ... var request = $.get('url'); request.done(function(data){$('body').append(data);});